# indexof error html page

Tags: android

I have an error when i'm going to do this operation:

```
if(file.indexOf("message") > 0)
   txtview.setText(file.indexOf("message"));
```

Where is the problem? The var file contains the html source of a web page.

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
txtview.setText(""+file.indexOf("message"));
```

you pass the integer value while this method require string